# how to evaluate the source of an image from properties of a react component which I have give it as a prop?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, create-react-app

I'm not able to use the component's prop for giving the src of an image which I imported from the path in my component's JavaScript file. I have already broken the props using syntax.

I have tried many formats:

```
src={`${src}`}
src =src
src={src}
src={{src}}
src={`${src}`}
```

No compiling error
This is my code>

```
import React from 'react';
import './Card.css';
import 'tachyons';
import aryan from "./images/aryan.jpg";
import azeem from "./images/azeem.jpg";
import simran from "./images/simran.jpg";
import vidushi from "./images/vidushi.jpg";
import shubham from "./images/shubham.jpg";
import bobby from "./images/bobby.jpg";

const Card=({id,name,source,username,email}) =>{

    return (
    <div className='pa3 br3 dib bg-light-green ma2 grow bw2 shadow-5'>
      <img src= {source}
       alt="Test"/>
      <div className='tc f3'> 
      <h4>{`${name}`}</h4>
      <h5>{`${username}`}</h5>
      <p className='f5'>{`${email}`}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    )

}
export default Card;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). We can't help you with code we can't see. Please update the question with code showing **exactly** how you get `src` and what your actual component code trying to use `src` looks like. `src={src}` is correct assuming `src` is a string.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=react+native+src+parameter

Answer (score 0):

for your reference:

```
<img src="/assets/img/background.png"/>
<img src={"/assets/img/background.png"}/>
```